# NMMAPS availability?

Tags: geospatial, medical, time-series, environment

The [National Morbidity, Mortality, and Air Pollution Study (NMMAPS)](https://www.healtheffects.org/publication/national-morbidity-mortality-and-air-pollution-study-part-i-methods-and-methodologic)
was a large national study of air pollution and health in the United States. The  study examined 108 cities spanning the years  from 1987 to 2000. 
However initially it was available at [Health and Air Pollution Surveillance System (iHAPSS)](http://www.ihapss.jhsph.edu/), after 2011 it was removed from the site.

Could you advise where from can the NMMAPS data be obtained?

Comment: Perhaps you could contact them (biostat@jhsph.edu) or ask Roger D. Peng (rpeng@jhsph.edu).

Comment: the localities still show up in the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.ihapss.jhsph.edu:80/data/NMMAPS//*. you could scrape them as a last resort...

Comment: i think it is here, but i don't use R so i'm not 100%; if so, lmk and i'll post as your answer: https://biostats.bepress.com/jhubiostat/paper44/

Comment: la data: https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/BigData/assignments/A6.pdf

Comment: chicago data: http://zevross.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/chicago-nmmaps.csv

Comment: @Stanslav Kralin, thanks for the contacts. I would try if fail to find.

Comment: @albert, about biostats.bepress.com/jhubiostat/paper44. The library you referred I'm actually trying to use (there's a variation of R package to access NMMAPS called NMMAPSlite) however they are referencing to the underlying database, which is removed. BTW thanks a lot for Time Machine and other references. I'll check them and be back.

Comment: @albert, I checked and it is only exerpt from the data, however I need the database. As of Time Machine it gives the html and images files the database itself is not accessible.

Comment: so the data in the html tables is not what you want? thats not data?

Comment: @albert, unfortunately not. These are summaries of the underlying data. I need to make some statistical inferences and you cannot do it with summaries.